# Ping work but Java code fails with host is unreachable in Docker

Tags: java, networking, docker, docker-compose

I'm stumped on a docker and Java networking issue. I have several containers started via docker-compose. Some need to talk to others. For example one container starts RabbitMQ, and another connect to it. Everything works fine if I use in the URLs I connect with the container names. However, I'd like to use the actual docker host name address (so that the configuration file I use can be used from external machines outside of docker containers) and this fails weirdly.
So let's say I have two containers:

- rabbitmq
- messageconsumer

If messageconsumer is configured to access `amqp://rabbitmq:5672`, it connects fine. However my containers are running say on host `docker.mycompany.com`. If I use `amqp://docker.mycompany.com:5672` as the url, my messageconsumer java code barfs with `java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Host is unreachable`.

However, if I start a shell in the messageconsumer container, `ping docker.mycompany.com` works! Why does the shell and ping find the host address, but not Java? My image is based on openjdk:alpine.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Possibly related: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/

Comment: Are you mapping the port from the container to the host? Docker doesn't do this by default, so whilst amqp://rabbitmq:5672 will resolve and connect between containers on the same Docker network, amqp://docker.mycompany.com:5672 would not connect unless you have specifically configured it as such.

Comment: Yes, the port is mapped and I can access containers from the outside.

Comment: does telnet work on the port?

Comment: I don't have telnet in the image, but trying Java code on different opened ports didn't work either. It works in host network mode, though, so I guess this is by design. I reworked my app differently to get around the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just went through the same thing.  I don't have an in-depth answer, and probably won't, but it looks like using HOST networking resolved this.

I will not claim that this ideal, but it should get you going until someone comes up with a better answer.